# Apache redirect all to www https

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

I am currently using the following in my `.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
```

..however I also want all requests to be redirected to `https://www.example.com`. As it stands any requests for `http://example.com` or `https://example.com` go to `https://example.com`. I have tried various methods in redirecting however seem to be only able to get all requests to `http www` or all requests to `https`, I can't figure it to get both.

Also any rule needs to include the original filename requested e.g a request for `http://example.com/contact.php` should be redirected to `https://www.example.com/contact.php`.

Any help or pointers would be much appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use that:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www\. [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://www.exemple.com%{REQUEST_URI} [NE,R=301,L]
```

Comment: Sorry unable to add links. It redirects to "https // www." only with nothing else.